# Strange Guice injection error

Tags: java, dependency-injection, constructor, guice, guava

I have a very strange error when trying to inject with constructor with Guice. There is a particular line in the constructor as the following:

```
@Inject
public RoundRobinAssigner(
        ... arguments
        ) {
            ...stuff

    assignments = Sets.synchronizedNavigableSet(Sets.<CountingEntry<String>>newTreeSet());
}
```

This fails upon injection with the following.

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.synchronizedNavigableSet(Ljava/util/NavigableSet;)Ljava/util/NavigableSet;
  at edu.harvard.econcs.turkserver.util.RoundRobinAssigner.<init>(RoundRobinAssigner.java:46)
  at edu.harvard.econcs.turkserver.util.RoundRobinAssigner.class(RoundRobinAssigner.java:40)
  while locating edu.harvard.econcs.turkserver.util.RoundRobinAssigner
```

But if I remove the `Sets.synchronizedNavigableSet()` wrapping, things inject just fine.

```
@Inject
public RoundRobinAssigner(
        ... arguments
        ) {     
            ...stuff

    assignments = Sets.<CountingEntry<String>>newTreeSet();

}
```

Clearly, this is suboptimal as I want to use the synchronized set. Is there any reason why a Guice-called instructor would behave any differently than a normal one? Neither of these code has any compile problems and the `Sets` class from guava has too have been loaded, so I have no idea what is causing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *suspect* you're just seeing a problem which you'd otherwise see elsewhere - basically because Guice is involved when loading up the class via reflection, the "link time" error of `Sets.synchronizedNavigableSet` being unavailable is shown within the context of Guice instead of in a "normal" constructor call.

[`synchronizedNavigableSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#synchronizedNavigableSet-java.util.NavigableSet-) was only introduced in 13.0 - is it possible that you're *compiling* against that, but *running* against an older version of Guava?

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the issue. Two conflicting declarations of Guava in different projects' `pom.xml`. Eclipse was using the newest one to compile but running was obeying the actual Maven rules, causing the error.